# Accessing/Passing values between Widgets

Tags: flutter

I was wondering what would be the best way to access/pass variables between widgets. For example,

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  int number = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Jungle Book',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Jungle Book')),
        drawer: new AppMenu(),
        body: new MainPageManager(),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(onPressed: null,child: new Icon(Icons.shuffle),),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPageManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageManagerState createState() => _MainPageManagerState();
}

class _MainPageManagerState extends State<MainPageManager> {
  List<String> keys = ["flamingo"];  // more to add later
  final _random = new Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: new Image.asset('images/'+keys[_random.nextInt(keys.length)]+'.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,)
    );
  }
}
```

If I need to pass a value during the floatingActionButton.OnPressed to the MainPageManager, what would be best way to do it.

What am attempting to do is, when the FloatingActionButton is pressed, i need to update the MainPageManager with a new image.

I read somewhere that using Global keys is not a good idea. What could be alternative ?
PS: am more of a beginner with flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter is not opinionated about how you approach state management.

Since `MainPageManager` is a direct child of `MyApp` you could turn `MyApp` into a stateful widget and `MainPageManager` into a stateless widget instead, as you are not using the setState method at all in your `MainPageManager`. Then, in your `onPressed` callback you'd use the `setState` method to set the state of your `MyApp` component, which will cause flutter to rebuild `MyApp` and all child widgets (so `MainPageManager` will be rebuild as well).

The last thing to do would be to add a property to your now stateless `MainPageManager`, that you'd pass down to that component.

**Example:**

```
class MainPageManager extends StatelessWidget {
  final String value;

  MainPageManager({this.value});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("$value"),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _valueBinding;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _valueBinding = "Test";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        MainPageManager(
          value: _valueBinding,
        ),
        MaterialButton(onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _valueBinding = "This will be shown in MainPageManager";
          });
        }, child: Text("Update Value"),)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**For more complex use-cases:**

Flutter comes with a state-management solution called `InheritedWidget`. However, the API is not that convenient and the flutter team actually promotes using [a package called Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) instead, which builds on `InheritedWidget`.

If your app grows really big I actually recommend using the [BloC pattern](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#bloc--rx) instead.